# Simple Java-based deployment tool

Tags: java, linux, grails, maven

I'm looking for a very simple deployment tool for JVM projects (Java, Spring, Grails, etc), with following features:

- don't require dedicated server/agent/etc, I want to run deployment from one developer machine (or from CI server) as simple console command
- don't requires any special server configuration, and not supposed to make server configuration for you
- just upload a WAR using SCP, or ideally using rsync (updating only changed files)
- (ideally) static files upload to s3/cloudfront
- can run command on remote server (restarting a tomcat service)
- store few latest version on server, and ability to rollback to any of them (basically it should be a update of a symlink)
- can be configured to use different servers (test, staging and production)
- (ideally) have a Maven plugin or Grails plugin
- support uploading to few servers in parallel

Should be something like:

```
$ deploytool staging deploy 
$ deploytool staging rollback
```

or

```
$ mvn deploytool:deploy -P staging
$ mvn deploytool:rollback -P staging
```

Basically it's just a:

1. compile + test + build archive
2. create 'date' directory on server (`/.../application/version-%date%/`)
3. upload WAR content into this directory, from local maching
4. update symlink from previous (`/.../application/current/` -> `/.../application/version-%date%/`
5. restart tomcat (`sudo service tomcat7 restart`)
6. delete directory with oldest version (keep only last 5 versions, or versions for last 45 days)
7. if something is wrong - update symlink to previous version (and restart tomcat)

I've taken a look at Puppet and JClouds, but seemst that it's different thing, more about cluster configuration, not deployment. Currently i'm using Ruby Capistrano for one project, and bash scripts for another. Capistrano is good, but requires installation of rvm, ruby, gems, etc, it's not working well for non-ruby team, and requires a lot of customizations for java project.

So, i'm wondering, is there any Capistrano-like tool for Java/JVM projects?

Comment: have you looked at luntbuild? Its whats we use, and seems to be similar to what you are looking for. I am just a developer who uses it and not the luntbuild admin so I am not if it has ALL of the featuresyou are looking for but it couldnt hurt to look.

Comment: As I see from offsite, luntbuild is a CI server. right?

Comment: You want a very robust tool that doesn't require any setup, but works for your environment. About the only thing you will be able to do is script a build tool + scripted file management.

Comment: @cdeszaq right. capistrano, for example, is written in ruby, but ruby has really weird setup. At other hand, we have JVM installed, and i'm sure it's full featured language, it should be enough for such tool

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `maven-compiler-plugin`, `maven-surefire-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` to build
2. Use `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to create property with current timestamp value
3. Use `wagon-maven-plugin` with generated timestamp value to upload war to staging server
4. Use `sshexec-maven-plugin` to start shell scripts which will restart tomcat with application for selected version

Comment: Thanks! It's kind of bash script rewritten in maven, but I found some interesting plugins, thanks!